# Is every lambda function an anonymous class?

Tags: c++, c++11

```
auto a = [](){};
auto b = [](){};
vector<decltype(a)> v;
v.push_back(a); //ok
v.push_back(b); //compiler error
```

a and b have different type.

I am wondering if each lambda function actually is kind of anonymous class, whenever we create a lambda function, we create a new class with a random name which only visible to compiler ?

Comment: Yes. Each lambda introduces its own, unique and anonymous type.

Comment: Lambdas **with no captures** such as yours are convertible to function pointers.  That will allow your sample code to compile with the vector type `vector< void(*)() >`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, every lambda introduces its own unique type.

Now the same lambda can have multiple closures (lambda instances) associated with it in a few ways.  C++14 return type deduction is the easiest:

```
auto nothing() {
  return []{};
}
```

will always return the same type, but different instances.  Similar things can be done by copying a lambda closure, or by passing a lambda in a type deduction context to a template function and storing it.

Comment: I wonder if there's any way of returning a local lambda from a function in C++11. I know you can do this by returning a `std::function`, but can you do exactly what you did above in C++11?

Comment: @vsoftco no, there is not.  You can only pass the lambdas "up" from where they are declared in C++11: you can pass one "in and out" to a subfunction, but the return type of a function (in C++11) is determined before its body is parsed (except, of course, lambdas bodies).  `auto f = []{ return [](int x){return x+1}; };` is a function objects whose `operator()` returns a lambda.

Comment: ... or indeed by using the lambda in a function which is called more than once, or in a loop that iterates more than once, which is the usual.

Comment: @cheer I was going for 2 instances at the same time, really.  I guess at different times is still two instances.